# Mosaicagem em Python ou C++?

Tags: python, opencv

Estou desenvolvendo um programa que, no futuro, pretendo transformar em app para android. Estou desenvolvendo em Python, minha ideia era usar o kivy para desenvolver o app inteiro.

Na atual etapa estou tendo problemas ao gerar um mosaico de imagens. O código funciona (desenvolvi com base neste tutorial: https://towardsdatascience.com/image-stitching-using-opencv-817779c86a83), o problema é que está muito lerdo, talvez pelo tamanho das imagens (4032 x 3024). Um conjunto de 4 imagens levou cerca de 20 minutos para mosaicar no meu notebook (i7 6a gen. e 8 GB de RAM), isto vai ficar inviável de rodar no android.

Visto isto, estou busanco soluções para torná-lo mais rápido. Talvez reescrever o código para uma linguagem mais rápida como C++, o que acham? Alguma sugestão para otimizar a velocidade de execução do código?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fazer em C++ não vai deixar isso muito mais rápido. 
Isso por que apesar de Python ser sim uma linguagem lenta, todas as chamadas que realmente consomem recursos nesse algoritmo (e em outros similares), são executadas em código nativo.

Isso é: quando você chama algo como `matches = bf.knnMatch(des1,des2, k=2)` (que possivelmente é uma das chamadas que consome mais tempo), tudo o que é executado já é em código nativo, escrito em uma linguagem otimizada. Não só isso, como está numa biblioteca que é otimizada ao longo de vários anos por dezenas ou centenas de voluntários - possivelmente fazendo uso de recursos como SIMD ou das próprias GPUs. Se você re-escrever o algoritmo todo em C++, vai ter uma performance certamente inverior ao OpenCV. Se você fizer um código em C++ usando também a OpenCV, vai estar usando **exatamente** o mesmo código que é usado a partir do Python.

Você não postou todo o seu código, e nem fez um [profiling](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#introduction-to-the-profilers)- então não é possível ajudar com detalhes. Mas sim, provavelmente o problema é por conta do tamanho das imagens (muitos algoritmos acadêmicos são desenvolvidos com imagens quase "simbólicas" em tamanho comparadas com o tamanho de fotos reais). Nesse caso, tudo o que você precisa fazer é *diminuir* as imagens antes de chamar os algoritmos custosos - no trecho:

```
img_ = cv2.imread(‘right.JPG’)
img1 = cv2.cvtColor(img_,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img = cv2.imread(‘left.JPG’)
img2 = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

que separa cópias em preto e branco img1 e img2 onde serão executados os algoritmos, aproveite e mande um resize  -  para esses tamanhs de imagem talvez 10% da imagem seja o suficiente para esse algorítimo(isso é, passar de 4000 para 400px de largura) - e nesse caso, o programa todo pode rodar até 100X mais rápido.

E aí, após obter as coordenadas de encaixe pelos algoritmos do OpenCV, é só multiplicar os valores de volta pelo fator de escala antes de plotar as imagens finais (coloridas) com o matplotlib.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda! Como se trata de um código que desenvolvo no meu trabalho, não fui autorizado a postar por inteiro, a mosaicagem é apenas uma das etapas. Novamente, muito obrigado!

Comment: Fiz algumas modificações que tornaram o código mais rápido. Uma delas foi a linguagem, reescrevi em C++ usando também o OpenCV, houve um salto grande no tempo de execução com as imagens no tamanho original, em Python estava levando cerca de 20 minutos, em C++ caiu para cerca de 7 minutos. Ao usar a sua dica, jsbueno, reduzi ainda mais o tempo de execução, consegui alcançar cerca de 37 segundos, o que para a minha aplicação está ótimo.

Uma pena a pergunta ter sido fechada, para mim estava claro o suficiente que eu estava buscando dicas de otimização da velocidade de execução do código...